# Requests using smtplib module denied

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I have been using the smtplib module in python to send text messages from a gmail account and my requests to connect to the server recently started being denied. My code isn't anything special:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP( "smtp.gmail.com", 587 )
server.starttls()
server.login( '<gmail_address>', '<gmail_password>’ )
server.sendmail( '<from>', '<number>@mms.att.net', '<msg>’ )
```

An error is thrown at the 4th line

```
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534,
```

and gmail notifies me that they have blocked a sign-in attempt from an app, because it didn't meet modern security requirements.

I'm hoping to find a work around that allows me to continue sending SMS messages using the smtplib module.

Comment: Try this: http://serverfault.com/questions/635139/how-to-fix-send-mail-authorization-failed-534-5-7-14

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google explain that you can [lower your security settings](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) but they don't rcommend it, and give precious little in the way of advice apart from that.